# How to prove the following inequality for a function?

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, functional-inequalities

I have function $$D(M\gamma)=\frac{M\gamma K}{K+\gamma(M\gamma-1)}\tag{1}$$ where $K$ is some positive constant. In this case, how to show that $$D(M(\gamma-1))<D(M\gamma),~~\text{for  } \gamma<\bigg\lceil\sqrt{\frac{K}{M}}\bigg\rceil.\tag{2}$$

My Try:

I tried to show that $$D(M\gamma)-D(M(\gamma-1))>0$$ which after some manipulations results in following inequality $$\sqrt{\frac{K}{M}+1}>\gamma$$ But I think this does not mean that $$D(M(\gamma-1))<D(M\gamma),~~\text{for  } \gamma<\bigg\lceil\sqrt{\frac{K}{M}}\bigg\rceil$$ because $$\sqrt{x+1}-\lceil\sqrt{x}\rceil$$ is not always greater than zero. So, How to prove the inequality in (2) for the function presented in (1). Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: But $\frac{M\gamma K}{K+\gamma(M\gamma-1)}$ is not a function of $M\gamma$...

Comment: then whose function is it?

Comment: @FabioLucchini as I am assuming $M$ to be constant. Then $\gamma$ is a variable and $D(M\gamma)$ is a function of $\gamma$

Comment: You can consider as function of $\gamma$ but not of $M\gamma$.

Comment: Can you write down the required inequality explicity (i.e. not in term of $D(M\gamma)$)?

Comment: @FabioLucchini actually the function that is to be maximized is as follows $$D(n)=\frac{nK}{K+\bigg\lceil\frac{n}{M}\bigg\rceil(n-1)}.$$ Now if we put $n=M\gamma$ with $\gamma$ an integer we get $$D(M\gamma)=\frac{M\gamma K}{K+\gamma(M\gamma-1)}$$

Comment: @FabioLucchini BTW why did you remove your answer?

Comment: I need to review my answer.

Comment: @FabioLucchini I think the derivative part of your answer is right and also the quasiconcave nature of the function that you showed in your answer is also correct. But I did not understand the later part.